# Convexity-Quasiconvexity differences and implications

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

So we have the following theorem:

> Let $f : A ⊆ \mathbb{R}^n $ convex (concave) on $A$ convex and let
>   $x_0$ be a critical point. Then x_0 is a global minimum (maximum)
>   point for $f$ in A.

What would change, if $f$ was quasiconcave/quasiconvex?

Answer (score 3):

The theorem would be false.  Consider:

$$
f(x) = x^3
$$

Then $f$ is strictly quasi-concave, strictly quasi-convex, and there is a unique critical point which is neither a local nor global minima (nor maxima).

> **Edit**: One example of the use of quasi-concavity in maximization problems is from game theory.  Suppose for some agent $i$, their utility $u_i(s_i, s_{-i})$ depends upon their choice of strategy ($s_i)$ and the choice of strategy of all the other opponents ($s_{-i}$, where $-i$ may be read as 'not $i$').  For a given choice of strategy $s_{-i}$ by the opponents, define:
>   $$
> BR_i(s_{-i}) = \textrm{arg max}_{\tilde{s}} u_i(\tilde{s}, s_{-i})
> $$
>   to be the utility-maximizing choices of response (the 'best response' correspondence).  Insofar as the set of strategies of $i$ is convex and for each $s_{-i}$ $u_i$ is quasiconcave in $s_i$, $BR_i$ will have convex values as a correpsondence.  This, coupled with a number of nice [continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_theorem) properties it will generally possess, allow us to easily [guarantee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakutani_fixed-point_theorem) the existence of equilibria.

In essence, on a convex domain, quasiconcavity implies the set of maximizers is convex (resp. quasiconvexity and minimizers).

Comment: So how can quasiconvexity/concavity help In an optimization problem

Comment: @LearningProb It helps for a couple reasons.  The example I gave is meant to show that things do change; the origin of it though is that any monotone $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is both quasi-concave and quasi-convex.  See my edit for an instance of where this is useful.

Answer (score 1):

For quasi-convex (-concave) functions the sets of global minima (maxima) are convex.